# Whoops! Lost connection to websocket error, while fetching data from a microservice through spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, stomp, spring-websocket, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to build a socket connection between multiple services in a microservice environment built in Spring Boot.

I have a room service running at port `8082` requesting data through socket from message service at port `8084`. These services are registered under Spring Cloud gateway running in port `9000`.
The gateway `application.yml` is as follows:

```
server:
  port: 9000
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: user-service
          uri: lb://user-service
          predicates:
          - Path=/user/**
        - id: room-service
          uri: lb://room-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/room/**
        - id: message-service
          uri: ws://message-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/message/**

  application:
    name: gateway-service
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

WebSocketConfiguration in message-service is as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

The controller class in message-service is as follows:

```java
@Controller
public class WebSocketController {
  @MessageMapping("/chat")
    @SendTo("/topic/messages")
    public MessageDTO sendMessage(MessageDTO message) {
    // Some tasks performed here, which are irrelevant to this case
    return message;
    }
}
```

Below is code snippet from room-service for establishing and getting messages through socket

```js
<script>
    var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:9000/websocket'); // Use the API gateway URL
    var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        var roomId = 1001;
        console.log("connected: " + frame );
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/messages', function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am getting error in establishing connection to the WebSocket server as:

```
Opening Web Socket...
Whoops! Lost connection to http://localhost:9000/websocket
```

When tried to test through Postman with request type `WebSocket` and URL: `ws://localhost:9000/websocket`, it gave error message as:

```
Could not connect to ws://localhost:9000/websocket
14:43:04
Error: Unexpected server response: 404
Handshake Details
Request URL: http://localhost:9000/websocket
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Request Headers
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: H2yiJVL2lXj86xhx57uKww==
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
```

I'm just learning these concepts, and I do not understand where am I going wrong.